# How do you prevent repeated MsgBox firing in the Form_Delete event?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a datasheet form which is making it easy for users to select all records and delete. I thought of writing a VBA code that prevents users from deleting the records if more than 20 records are selected. Then I wrote this code but the problem is that the message fires for every record. Has someone ever come across this? Please see below.

```
  Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
  If Me.SelHeight > 20 Then
      Cancel = True
      MsgBox ("Bulk deletion is not allowed!")
 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Never seen this requirement. Probably have to prevent any record delete by setting form AllowDeletions to no then use code behind maybe form DoubleClick event to delete record with DELETE sql action. Deleting records should be a rare occurrence. Why are users allowed to delete?

Comment: As alternative to my solution, you can mark a record as deleted (additiomal field`IsDeleted`) and update that flag on delete. If you delete records you should compress the database to shrink it.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher thanks for your help but your code doesn't fire up the massage.

Comment: @June7 a user has mentioned that they have selected the entire data from the datasheet with the intention to copy but ended up deleting everything.

Comment: The preventing deletion here is not the problem anymore. The repeated massage firing is for every record is. Perhaps I should change the title of the post to "How do you prevent repeated MsgBox firing in the Form_Delete event?"

Comment: Answer: don't use a messagebox in`Form_Deleted`use`Form_AfterDelConfirm`what is designed for that task! See my new answer-

Answer (score 0):

If you get confused about [BeforeDelConfirm event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.beforedelconfirm(even)) not fired, like I got, check if the`Confirm Record Changes`Option is set. If not, event is not raised.

Using`BeforeDelConfirm`and`AfterDelConfirm`, this task is a lot simpler.

On top of form module

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim deleteCount As Long
Private Const MaxDeleteRows As Long = 20 ' set this constant to the number of rows that can be deleted at once
```

event code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
  If deleteCount > MaxDeleteRows Then
    MsgBox ("Bulk deletion is not allowed!")
  End If
  deleteCount = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeDelConfirm(Cancel As Integer, Response As Integer)
  If deleteCount > MaxDeleteRows Then
    Cancel = True
  End If
  Response = acDataErrContinue
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
  If deleteCount = 0 Then
    deleteCount = Me.SelHeight
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Deactivate()
 ' Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", False ' needed if you want to have Confirm Record Changes off elsewhere
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activate()
 ' Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", True ' needed if you want to have Confirm Record Changes off elsewhere (turns it on here)
End Sub
```

Comment: from your code: Response = acDataErrContinue removes the Access confirmation message if less than 20 records are selected. If I remove the line it fires but then if a user selects more than 20 records, the after delete confirmation fails. Is there a way of using them both or something close?

Comment: What Office version? If removed on Access 2007 after delete is fired. You checked not fireing with a breakpoint?`Confirm Record Changes`is on?

Comment: We use 2007, 2013 and 2016 depending on the site a user is located. The idea is for the user to only receive one message if more than records are selected through the datasheet view and cancel delete, but allow delete if less than 20 records are selected. I know this may be difficult task to accomplish in vba.